# Wrong character encoding in R console

Tags: mysql, r, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem with encoding after fetching data from MySQL database. Please see attached code:

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='', dbname='', host='localhost')
dbGetQuery(mydb, "SET NAMES 'utf8'")
rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT body_prepared FROM articles")
data = fetch(rs, n=-1)

print(data)    
internetovĂ˝ televĂ­zor mĂşdry obyÄŤajnĂ˝
```

After used command `print(data)` I should see `internetový televízor múdry obyčajný`(It is slovak languague), but I see `internetovĂ˝ televĂ­zor mĂşdry obyÄŤajnĂ`.

I tried to run R via Rgui and also via Rstudio, but that didn't have any effect and result was same in Rgui and also Rstudio.
I tried to use `enc2utf8(data[[1]])` or change various types encoding by `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_EN.UTF-8")`, but these commands werent helpful. 
I thought, there is problem on Mysql side, but there is set correct utf-8 encoding for my column.

I don't know where can be the problem. It's made me mad.
Can you help with this problem? I will be very gratuful.

For complete information, here is my sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
    R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Slovak_Slovakia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovak_Slovakia.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Slovak_Slovakia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=Slovak_Slovakia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RMySQL_0.10.2 DBI_0.3.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

**UPDATE**

I rewrote `dbGetQuery(mydb, "SET NAMES 'utf8'")` to `dbGetQuery(mydb, "SET NAMES 'cp1250'")` and suddenly it showed correct result.

Answer (score 1):

The data was stored incorrectly.  Probably you had the text encoded in utf8 bytes, but SET NAMES was latin1 or cp1250 when you did the INSERT, and the CHARACTER SET of the column is latin1 or cp1250.  Is all of this correct?  If so, we can proceed with fixing the data.  If not, please provide details.

Also, provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to verify what bytes were stored.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see the details of the column.

Comment: CHARACTER SET is utf-8. I rewrite `dbGetQuery(mydb, "SET NAMES 'utf8'")` to `dbGetQuery(mydb, "SET NAMES 'cp1250'")` and now `print(data)` show correct result. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me. The text appears correctly when using my SQLite Data Browser, but when I read it into R (with locale settings similar as yours, although 1252 and not 1250), all diacritic signs are problematic. Here's an example:

```
con <- dbConnect(drv = SQLite(), dbname=bdclient)
config$autres <- dbReadTable(con, "config_autres")
config$autres$msg_err_import
[1] "<h4>Un problÃ¨me est survenu lors de lâ€™importation de nouvelles donnÃ©es; 
    aucun rapport nâ€™a Ã©tÃ© produit. [...]"
```

And using `iconv`, with `from = "UTF-8"` parameter:

```
iconv(config$autres$msg_err_import, from = "UTF-8")
[1] "<h4>Un problème est survenu lors de l’importation de nouvelles données; 
    aucun rapport n’a été produit. [...]"
```